# Protecting Azure Function Keys in client side application

Tags: jquery, azure, security, azure-functions, azure-cdn

I have been experimenting with Azure Functions.

I want to call a HTTP Trigger function from a static website via jQuery. I have the static website setup in Azure Blob Storage, using the Verizon CDN. That is all working correctly.

However, I want to limit the access to only my website. 
I want to secure the Function via the AuthorizationLevel 'Function' - meaning I need to pass the API key with the request. 
However, this would mean having the key on the static webpage, meaning anyone who viewed the source of the page would be able to get the call and call the Function.

Is there a way I can circumvent this? 
I had thought about being able to add a HTTPHeader to the CDN?
I had also thought about being able to request something on the Function side to only allow certain websites to make the request.

I am a bit lost with this, and perhaps it cannot be done this simply.

Comment: If you are using Azure to host you website, Azure has the functionality to validate this already. Search on the Azure console for this.option. connect the website to the blob storage and that would do the job for you. Sorry I forgot the exact steps and I don't have access to Azure at the moment, but I've done it before

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes the website is hosted in Azure Blob Storage, and I am accessing an Azure HTTP Function. I couldn't find anything regarding this.option - do you have any more to go on? Would you be able to check when you're back with access to Azure please?

Answer (score 1):

Preferably, using the best practices, you should use Verizon Premium CDN, to be able to use routing rules, and then use Azure API Management to abstract the client from your APIs, and have a way to protect them by applying throttling rules, request limit, cache, etc.

The rules you can configure are using [URL Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features#url-rewrite) for requests with to your functions( e.g. /api) and the [Bypass Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features#bypass-cache) rule for any requests related to dynamic data that you do not want to cache.

Please have a look [at this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/serverless/web-app) on Microsoft documentation that shows the diagram and explains the process.

Comment: I have used URL Rewrite rules to enforce HTTPS and also www domain, as I am using Verizon Premium CDN already, but not sure what else I could do with that to solve my problem. 
That article looks in depth, and I had a look at API management, but it looks very complex. I was hoping for a simpler solution!

Comment: API Management is not complex. And it will give you much more flexibility than just using CORS rules on your Function App. Basically you will create an endpoint on API Management, and that endpoint will expose all the requests you need to perform to your Functions, and then the endpoint will have a backend API that is your Function.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally from a security point of view, there is no way (that I know of at least) to authenticate a public client like a browser application.
Since the requests must be allowed from user machines without authentication, the endpoints must be left open.
Using the function key is pretty pointless if it is distributed to the front-end anyway.

You can use CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) to limit requests to only come from your website.
This doesn't prevent someone from making the requests, but it tells browsers not to allow the requests from the wrong origins.
Someone could still make requests from a back-end application to your functions (since CORS is ignored there), but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was my concern that being a client side app I'd need to store the key there. I just couldn't believe I was the only person trying to achieve this and wondered if there was anything I had missed. In it's simplicity - I want to lock down an Azure HTTP Function to only my website, which has no authentication.